# Renaming the value returned by Lambda Function in Aggregate Operation

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I am looking to display the value of various percentiles against each group of Publishers in a dataset. I am trying the below:

```
vg.groupby(['Publisher']).agg({'Global_Sales':['mean','min','max','median',lambda x: x.quantile(0.5)]})
```

The few rows of the dataset are:

```
   Rank                       Name Platform    Year         Genre Publisher  \
0     1                 Wii Sports      Wii  2006.0        Sports  Nintendo   
1     2          Super Mario Bros.      NES  1985.0      Platform  Nintendo   
2     3             Mario Kart Wii      Wii  2008.0        Racing  Nintendo   
3     4          Wii Sports Resort      Wii  2009.0        Sports  Nintendo   
4     5   Pokemon Red/Pokemon Blue       GB  1996.0  Role-Playing  Nintendo   
5     6                     Tetris       GB  1989.0        Puzzle  Nintendo   
6     7      New Super Mario Bros.       DS  2006.0      Platform  Nintendo   
7     8                   Wii Play      Wii  2006.0          Misc  Nintendo   
8     9  New Super Mario Bros. Wii      Wii  2009.0      Platform  Nintendo   
9    10                  Duck Hunt      NES  1984.0       Shooter  Nintendo   

   NA_Sales  EUR_Sales  JAP_Sales  IND_Sales  Global_Sales  
0     41.49      29.02       3.77       8.46         82.74  
1     29.08       3.58       6.81       0.77         40.24  
2     15.85      12.88       3.79       3.31         35.82  
3     15.75      11.01       3.28       2.96         33.00  
4     11.27       8.89      10.22       1.00         31.37  
5     23.20       2.26       4.22       0.58         30.26  
6     11.38       9.23       6.50       2.90         30.01  
7     14.03       9.20       2.93       2.85         29.02  
8     14.59       7.06       4.70       2.26         28.62  
9     26.93       0.63       0.28       0.47         28.31
```

Now i want to give a name to <lambda_0> object returned. I am unable to do so. Please guide as i am new to Python and trying to build my basics.

Comment: @Cimbali Done the required. Please let me know if any other changes are required

Comment: No it’s ok @PythonLearner, the question is clear. On other questions you might want to provide desired output and maybe what you’re getting instead.

Comment: hi! Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [doc of `.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) you can also directly specify the column name in the `agg()` function as keyword arguments:

```
>>> vg.groupby(['Publisher']).agg(
...     min=('Global_Sales', 'min'),
...     foo=('Global_Sales', lambda x: x.quantile(0.5)),
... )
              min     foo
Publisher                
Nintendo   36.939  30.815
```

As you can see the arguments to these keyword args are the (column, aggregation function) tuples.